# Is $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, entire-functions

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in an open neighbhourhood of $z \in \mathbb C$. Given that the series 
$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{f^{(n)}(z)}$ converges absolutely, we can conclude that

1. $f$ is constant
2. $f$ is a polynomial
3. $f$ can be extended to an entire function
4. $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

My attempt : I take $f(z) = i$  for option D. as option D is clearly false. I don't know the other option  pliz help me and tell me the solution…

Comment: What does mean $f(z)=f(z)+f'(z)+\cdots$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ can be extended to the entire function$$F(w)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}(w-z)^n.$$This series converges abolutely, for every $w\in\mathbb C$, because you can apply Abel's test to the series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigl|f^{(n)}(z)\bigr|\frac{|w-z|^n}{n!}.$$Note that the series that defines $F$ is the Taylor series of $f$; therefore, $F(w)=f(w)$ in the neighborhood of $z$.

Comment: sorry for late reply,,,,and thanks a lots@Jose Cralos Santos

Comment: Sir, May I know, How $F(w)=f(w)$ in the neighbourhood $z$. $f(z)$ and $F(w)$ has different coefficients in the Taylor expansion. Right? Please help me.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I don't understand your doubt. Given a function $F$ defined by a power series $F(w)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(w-z)^n$, $F^{(n)}(z)=n!a_n$.

Comment: $$F(w)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}(w-z)^n.$$right? $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)$$. How these two are same in the neighbourhood of $z$.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I understand your doubt now. I assumed that when the OP wrote “$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)$ converges absolutely”, what she meant was just that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)$ converges absolutely, but **not** that it sum was $f(z)$. That can only happen for constant functions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes. I understood sir. Thank you very much. sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

By the absolute convergence of the series on the right, we can differentiate summand-wise. But then
$$ \begin{align}f^{(k)}(z)=&\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dz^k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dz^k}f^{(n)}(z)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n+k)}(z)\\&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)\quad-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}f^{(n)}(z)\\
&= f(z)-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}f^{(n)}(z)\\\end{align}.$$
For $k=1$, this gives us $f'(z)=f(z)-f(z)=0$, and for $k>1$,
$$ \begin{align}f^{(k)}(z)&=f(z)-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}f^{(n)}(z)\\&=f(z)-\sum_{n=0}^{k-2}f^{(n)}(z)-f^{(k-1)}(z)\\&=f^{(k-1)}(z)-f^{(k-1)}(z)\\&=0\end{align}$$
We conclude that the Taylor series of $f$, developed around $z$, has all coefficients $=0$ except for the constant term, i.e., $f$ is constant. Therefore claim (1) is true, as are claims (2) and (3), but not necessarily claim (4).

Comment: thanks @Hagen vonEitzen,,,,,,,,,,